# Electron Tray application: How to reference target balloon in event handler of balloon-clicked event?

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron *Tray* applications can show balloons using the *Tray.displayBalloon* method that takes an object with *title*, *content* and optional *icon* property.

To my knowledge, the balloon interface does not include a click or onClick property. The *Tray* class does have a *balloon-click* event that fires when a balloon is clicked as well as a *balloon-closed* and *balloon-show* event. However the *event* object passed to the callback function does not seem to include a reference to the balloon that dispatched the event. (the balloon that was displayed, clicked or closed)

```
tray.on('balloon-click', console.log)
tray.on('balloon-show', console.log)
tray.on('balloon-closed', console.log)
```

Log:

```
{ preventDefault: [Function: preventDefault],
  sender:
   Tray {
     _events:
      { 'balloon-click': [Function],
        'balloon-show': [Function: consoleLog] },
     _eventsCount: 2 } }
```

My Tray application sends balloon notifications from different sources. What happens when you click the balloon (where to navigate to or what window to open) kinda depends on what the balloon is saying.

I need a reference to the balloon that was clicked, not just that there was a balloon click somewhere at some point.

I can think of many ways to implement a solution ranging from a simple wrapper function and an *activeBalloon* variable to an entire BalloonManager class but I don't feel like wasting my time if I just overlooked this in the Electron API documentation.

> This question was also asked on discuss.atom.io in August 2017

Source: https://discuss.atom.io/t/tray-balloon-click-how-to-know-which-balloon-is-clicked/46744